# How does atof.c work? Subtracting an ASCII zero from an ASCII digit makes it an int? Am I missing something?

Tags: c

So as part of my C classes, for our first homework we are supposed to implement our own atof.c function, and then use it for some tasks. So, being the smart stay-at-home student I am I decided to look at the atof.c source code and adapt it to meet my needs. I think i'm on board with most of the operations that this function does, like counting the digits before and after the decimal point, however there is one line of code that I do not understand. I'm assuming this is the line that actually converts the ASCII digit into a digit of type int. Posting it here:

```
frac1 = 10*frac1 + (c - '0');
```

in the source code, c is the digit that they are processing, and frac1 is an int that stores some of the digits from the incoming ASCII string. but why does c- '0' work?? And as a followup, is there another way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Your question says “c is the digit that they are processing.” But a digit is a mark on paper or a symbol on a display or, abstractly, a mathematical entity. What type is `c`; how is it declared? What values do you think `c` can hold? What value do think it has when it represents a digit? What do you think the values are when it is representing digits 0 through 9? Also, do you know what `'0'` means in source code? (By the way, C implementations do not necessarily use ASCII.)

Comment: '0' is the ASCII char 0, c is a single char, stored in a register (declared as register char c)

Comment: As I noted, you cannot have a character stored in a register. A character is a symbol. You cannot store a symbol in a register—you cannot have a plus sign or an ampersand or a digit for three in a register. Registers or memory locations only have bits that store combinations of zeros and ones, which we interpret as various values. The values of a `char` are numbers, like 0 to 255 or −128 to +127. If `c` is declared as a `char`, and `c` **represents** the digit “0”, what do you think it **actually** in `c`? What are its bits? What number do those bits represent?

Comment: Gotcha. Yup, I vaguely remember this from the first week of class, and am beginning to get the sense that this question was super basic. Thank you for the refresher!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "text" in C. Just APIs that happen to treat integer values as text information. `char` is an integer type, and you can do math with it. Character literals are actually `int`s in C (in C++ they're `char`, but they're still usable as numeric values even there).

`'0'` is a nice way for humans to write "the ordinal value of the character for zero"; in ASCII, that's the number 48. Since the digits appear in order from `0` to `9` in all encodings I'm aware of, you can convert from the ordinal value in the encoding (e.g. ASCII) to actual numeric values by subtracting away `'0'` to get actual `int` values from `0` to `9`.

You could just as easily subtract `48` directly (when compiled, it would be impossible to tell which option you used; `48` and ASCII `'0'` are indistinguishable), it would just be less obvious what you were doing to other people reading your source code.

Comment: The C standard requires the codes for the digits to be consecutive and in order, in C 2018 5.2.1 3.

Comment: ShadowRanger, Detail: "Character literals are actually ints in C" --> In C, '0' is a _character constant_, not a _literal_.  C has _string literals_ and _compound literals_, but does not define a Character literal

Comment: @chux: “Literal” is a correct English word to use for this; it is not necessary for the C standard to define a word if its ordinary meaning is applicable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If C did not define string literals and compound literals, I'd agree with you that your concern applies here as much as this answer's uses "There is no such thing as "text" in C. "

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: If the question wanted language lawyer responses, I'd try to be more precise. But I'm mostly just trying to squash the OP's notion that there is a strong distinction between text and integers in C (they're title includes confusion from "Subtracting an ASCII zero from an ASCII digit makes it an int?", not realizing it was all integers to begin with). I'm not going to get too worried about common English usage vs. C spec usage of "literal" when they don't understand the basics, and aren't asking for language lawyering.

Comment: Literally, there is nothing stopping from making the answer more precise other than than the editing effort needed due to this answer introduced verbiage.  Your call.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The existence of the phrases “string literal” and “compound literal” shows you that “literal” has its own meaning common to those two phrases and distinct from them.

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII value of '0' is the 48'th character in code page 437 (IBM default character set). Similarly, '1' is the 49'th etc. Subtracting '0' instead of a magic number such as 48 is much clearer as far as self-documentation goes.

Comment: Even if the character value of '0' was not 48, `c - '0'` converts the the digit character to a value correctly.  Being ASCII is not needed here.